# How to solve the following nonlinear matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I want to find a matrix $X$ that satisfies the following matrix equation:
$$A+BX=XB+XCX$$
where $A,\ B,\ C$ are all square matrices, and $A,\ C$ are hermitian. Is there a general procedure to solve this kind of matrix equations? Finding a particular solution is enough.

Comment: Use Kronecker product (http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/reports/kronthesisschaecke04.pdf) (see in particular p. 11 of this M. Sc. document)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you very much for the hint. However, I still don't know how to deal with the quadratic term $XCX$.

Comment: Here is a reference : (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.330.1438&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Answer (score 1):

This Equation is called [Algebraic Riccati Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation) and is mostly used in control-theory. 
Often ones uses iterative approcahes to solve this. By starting with an Guess $X_0$ one can find an Error $E$ by setting $$
A+B(X_0 +E) =(X_0+E)B + (X_0+E)C(X_0+E)
$$
which is equal to
$$
(A+BX_0 -X_0D+X_0CX_0) + (B+X_0C)E = E(B+CX_0) + ECE
$$
which is of similar type.
Ignoring $ECE$ which is hopefully small, one can solve the resulting equation to get $E$. This results in $X_1 = X_0+E$ and we are back at the start...